# Exception : Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have several threads that write to the same int. Each thread increment the 
integer value. What is the simple way to synchronize the increment operation. 
The lock statement works only on Object so i can't use it. I tried also the 
following:

```
static int number=0;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(strtThread);
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void strtThread()
    {
        bool lockTaken = false;

        Monitor.Enter(number,ref lockTaken);
        try
        {
            Random rd = new Random();
            int ee = rd.Next(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(ee);
            Thread.Sleep(ee);
            number++;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally 
        {
            if (lockTaken)
            {
             Monitor.Exit(number);
            }

        }
    }
```

It gives me the following error:

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Interlocked.Increment Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) to automically increment an integer without locking:

```
public static void strtThread()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref number);
}
```

If you have multiple statements, you can create an [object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) instance that you can [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

```
private static int number = 0;
private static readonly object gate = new object();

public static void strtThread()
{
    lock (gate)
    {
       number++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: i want to do this using Monitor.Enter. please give me a code example using  Monitor.Enter. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Vero009: Why do you need to use Monitor.Enter? It's highly unusual not to use `lock`.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you bother with the `number`? I think that's the problem. Try this:

```
static Object locking = new Object();

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(strtThread);
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        new Thread(ts).Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void strtThread()
    {
        lock(locking) {
            try
            {
                Random rd = new Random();
                int ee = rd.Next(1000);
                Console.WriteLine(ee);
                Thread.Sleep(ee);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) provides an atomic increment.  The [Interlocked class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kczs5b5.aspx) in general "provides atomic operations for variables that are shared by multiple threads."